# xpath and csspath from HTML code for using in WebDriver

Tags: java, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<label for="widget_118_login_username">Username</label>
```

What's the xpath and csspath (cssSelector) to use in Selenium 2 (WebDriver)?

Answer (score 0):

The followings work fine for me:

Xpath: //label[@for='widget_118_login_username']

cssSelector: label[for=widget_118_login_username]